# maintain aspect ratio on browser resize

Tags: css, resize, width, grid-layout

The wrapper container css is width:auto; max-height:70%;

I want the divs to maintain their aspect ratio when browser window height changes.

jfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/7JNuU/

HTML

```
<div id="feedwrapper">

<!--FULL group-->
<div id="tile">
<div id="fullcell">1</div>
</div>
<!--FULL group-->

<!--4up group-->
<div id="tile">
<div id="solocell">1</div>
<div id="solocell">2</div>
<div id="solocell">3</div>
<div id="solocell">4</div>
</div>
<!--4up group-->

<!--2top group-->
<div id="tile">
<div id="solocell">1</div>
<div id="solocell">2</div>
<div id="cell2xbot">3</div>
</div>
<!--2top group-->
```

CSS

```
#feedwrapper{
width:auto;
max-height:70%;
top:80px;
bottom:60px;
margin-bottom:80px;
left:300px;
position:absolute;
background-color:#FFF;
white-space:nowrap;
display:block;
}
#tile{ position:relative; border:none; padding:0px; min-width:640px; height:100%; margin:0px 2px 2px 0px; background-color:#CC6; float:left;}

#fullcell{width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#F99; display:block;}
#solocell{ width:50%; height:50%; background-color:#36C; display:block; float:left;}
#cell2xbot{ width:100%; height:50%; background-color:#C93; display:block; float:left;}
#cell2xtop{ width:100%; height:50%; background-color:#C66; display:block; float:left;}
#cell2yleft{ width:50%; height:100%; background-color:#99C; display:block; float:left;}
#cell2yright{ width:50%; height:100%; background-color:#FC6; display:block; float:right;}
```

The page I'm working on is:  http://www.jordache.com/connect.php

The grid uses squares and rectangles.
50%x50% squares, 100% squares, 50%x/100%y rect, and 100%x/50%y rect.

There must be a simpler way.... grrrrr... help!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to develop a flexible-grid type of CSS framework, makes me think of Twitter-Bootstrap.  When do you need this by?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h4S3M/

Comment: Hello again, just curious, these images, are they mean to be part of the content?  If so, why place them in the background?  How is this page meant to be used, like a photo-gallery (sales sheet)?  Any additional information would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: the images are just for reference. The divs need to stay in proportion on window resize..